# Nginx/Gunicorn timeout when running query that takes 2+ minutes to complete on django

Tags: django, nginx, timeout, gunicorn

I'm running a query that takes maximum 3 minutes to complete with django, using `connections['report'].cursor()`

When I make a request to the view that execute that query, Nginx give me a timeout (that is presented in the view as "502 Bad Gateway").

What approach should I choose to overcome this issue? Should I increase the timeout setting or how can I make this asynchronous?

Answer (score 3):

**First approach (easiest)**: You can increase the timeout setting. This way your users will have to wait a long time. Not a good user experience.

**Second approach (moderate difficulty)**: If your users don't have to wait for that request (such as email sending), you could delegate that task to a background worker. In Django community, that's usually done by [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

**Third approach (the most difficult - best experience)**: Use [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [web sockets](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django). This will take a lot of time if you are new to these technologies.

Choose depending on your case. Hope it helps!